# How to replace non zero values with a particular integer using CUDA library?

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

I want to replace all the non zero elements of a device vector with integer 1. I specifically want to use only CUDA libraries to perform this operations.

Is there any thrust function that helps me out to achieve my result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a device vector:

```
thrust::device_vector<int> X;
```

you can use one of the thrust [algorithms](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__algorithms.html) like this:

```
thrust::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), X.begin(), [](int n) {
    return n ? 1 : 0;
});
```

or

```
thrust::replace_if(X.begin(), X.end(), [](int n) {
    return n != 0;
}, 1);
```